# What is the reason of the getting a clipped signal at the receiving end when using experimental tests

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

I am using a sine wave signal (for test) with the following scenario:

Computer #1 --> AWG --> DC bias (2.2 Voltage) --> light source --> lens *** wireless channel 2 meters *** --> lens --> APD --> Oscilloscope --> Computer #2.

I am wondering why the received signal is not symmetric, I mean the negative part is clipped. However, two weeks ago, I was performing the same test with same scenario and getting a normal signal which is very symmetric and it is not clipped at all.
The alone action I did is that I clicked reset bouton of the oscilloscope.

**NP**

When I modified the alignment between the lens and APD, the clipping has been changed as below pic. I think that some of signal was clipped by alignment or the mean and pk-pk values, highlighted in below pic too, have such relationship with that clipping. I am not sure yet why that happens when decreasing those values.

Comment: Standard debugging process applies: check the signal after every step in your signal chain and to isolate where the unexpected behavior occurs.

Comment: @Hilmar I checked it till the AWG, and the from the AWG till the oscilloscope, it is hard to check the signal except using this way. Do you know another way to be followed to debug the signal?

Comment: It would help to show a block diagram and explain your acronyms. What exactly are AWG and APD and where you can can attach a scope probe?

Comment: Try replacing the OFDM generator with a sine wave generator (or, if that's impractical, run data through the OFDM that will cause it to generate a single tone, or the smallest possible collection of tones).  Then zoom in on the (hopefully) sine wave.  The time domain distortion should be more apparent.

Comment: @TimWescott I made it sine wave signal and tested.  I updated the question according to the new signal. It is still clipped.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look *clipped* - it looks *compressed*.

Assuming APD means "avalanche photodiode",  remember that your system is strongly non-linear and your assumption that the amplitude distribution at the output is just a scaled version of that on the input simply is not backed by your system model.

We don't know how you set up your oscilloscope before resetting it. But many oscilloscopes have "math functions" that you can apply to the captured signal; try the $\sqrt{\;\;}$ or the logarithm, if these are available.

Comment: I updated the question, I think it is clear now that is clipped, right?   regarding the math functions, I am looking for them in the oscilloscope but did not find it!  maybe it is not supported.

Comment: Unlikely that a nike tek scope has none of them. But yeah, this looks clipped. So, you changed your bias somewhere, and this has nothing to do with the settings of your scope.

Comment: I see, I think it is from the APD, there is a relationship between that mean value in the pk-pk icone located at the bottom of osc screen and that clipping issue. When I modified the alignment of the APD and decreased that value for example till 330 m; that clipping changed. I updated the question to show that step too.